Level shifting 7.5-15V range to 0-3.3V range to read on a microcontroller
I have a microcontroller that is meant to read a voltage between 7.5-15 V range. The ADC for the microcontroller is 3.3 V max so I came up with the circuit shown below. It takes in 7.5-15 V input and turns into 0.25-1.75 V. I would like to get more resolution but cant find Zener diodes with specific voltages so I can’t do any better with this configuration. I need help with designing a circuit that will get better resolution.


How accurate is your 3.3V rail and how accurate do you need the measurement to be?

If you need a specific zener voltage, the TL431/TLV431 is a great help--little three-pin IC that acts like a programmable zener with two resistors to set the "zener voltage".

A better idea might be to oversample the ADC and take an average. Your fundamental issue with your approach is the hardware - you need wider voltage rails and ideally a negative rail to maximize the ADC dynamic range. That additional complexity my or may not be required for your app especially if you got uP clock cycles to burn.

If you change R2 to 8kΩ and add a 12kΩ resistor from the inverting input to ground you'll get more like 0.75 to 3.1V out for  7.5V to 15V in. This is just an example, you should do a worst-case analysis.
The op-amp has to sink current to get near 0V and source current to get near the 3.3V supply (which has a tolerance) and the resistors won't be exact, so don't call it too close.

If your 3.3 V supply is stable enough to use as a reference, then this circuit will work

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

If you 3.3 V supply is not suitable as a reference voltage, you can use a TL431 or other voltage reference, and I could calculate the resistor values you would need.
